# Why am I unable to import any of the images which are present in the public folder?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, react-fullstack

I'm currently working on NextJS, and I can't able to import the any of the images which are present in the public folder. I can go through folders but it is not fetching the images.

I used the following import line and HTML:

```
import profilePic from '../../public/images/profile/'

<main className= "flex items-center text-dark w-full min-h-screen">
    <Layout>
        <div className ="flex items-center justify-between w-full">
            <div>
                <Image src= {profilePic} alt="" className='w-full h-auto' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </Layout>
</main>
```

Thanks in advance for your help...!!!

Comment: Hi Pratik, could you provide more context for the HTML segment please? Was that all you used, what does it mean to "go through folders"?

Comment: I think, so you have to give the full image path as following: ```import profilePic from '../../public/images/profile/image-name.jpg'```

Answer (score 1):

When you're importing images, you need to specify the exact path to the image file. In your current import statement, you're specifying the folder itself, not a specific image file.

Maybe you want to do something like `../../public/images/profile/profile-pic.png`.

Plus, in Next.js, when you're importing images from the public folder, you only need to specify the path relative to the public folder itself. You don't need to include `../../public` in the path. This is because the public folder is automatically served as the root URL path.

So, if your image is located at `public/images/profile/profile-pic.png`, you can directly use `/images/profile/profile-pic.png` to reference the image. You don't need to include `../../public`.